# Uploading videos that are large in size to my hosting site

Tags: node.js, mongodb, video, heroku, video-streaming

I have created an online automation testing course comprising of 100+ videos. I have also created an web application using Node.js and mongodb.

I intend to allow users to sign up to my website and if they wish to become members then they will get access to the whole course.

My videos are currently 11.8gb! in size. I have compressed these down using HandBrake to 1.72gb (still large, I know) but I'm finding this tool crops the edges of my video (even though I specifically set it not to). Does anyone have any alternative tools that they recommend?

Also can someone advise on the hosting of these videos? I intend to use Heroku and Mlab but am concerned that the amount of data when users stream the videos could be costly...

Any advice greatly appreciated/welcomed.

Regards,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

The biggest thing to know up front is that heroku has an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem).
This is because every app deploy will create a stateless container, which is then run and recreated from scratch on next deploy.

This means on user upload, you cannot expect files stored on disk to still be there after the end of the request.
For this reason, you should send all uploaded files to a dedicated file storage system, such as [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) or [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

You can see the pricing for those services to estimate your cost.

Comment: Thanks Damien.

Sorry but could you explain further? 

Would it be correct to store all videos on Google Cloud or AWS S3 and then link to the videos through my website?

I've taken a look at the Google Cloud pricing, specifically the networking costs. When a user wishes to view my videos from my site then I believe this will start incurring costs. Please correct me if I'm wrong?

Essentially what I'm trying to avoid is for my videos to be available unless a member has paid for membership. This is why Youtube is not an option. Would something like Vimeo Pro be a good idea?

Comment: The reason I have mentioned Vimeo PRO is that you can hide your videos from their public directory, and also specify a particular domain on which the video may be embedded. This ensures your videos can only be embedded on your own site.

Then I would embed the video link on my app (hosted on Heroku) to the Vimeo cloud.

Comment: Youtube and Vimeo could definitely be a solution too (and possibly a simpler one, as you wouldn't have to setup a video player yourself, but just to embed the provided one).

Comment: Thanks Damian. I have re-read your original comment. Just so you know, I do not intend to allow users to upload their own videos. The videos will be uploaded by me (they are video tutorials). I only want users to be able to view the videos once they have paid for membership.

Thanks.